# What is, or was the meaning of "oncommon"?

Tags: meaning, history, literature

In Dickens' *David Copperfield*, there is an exchange between David and Mr Pegotty who arrives with his nephew Ham to visit him at school. It runs as follows:

*"Do you know how mama is, Mr Peggotty? I said. And how my dear, dear old Peggotty is?*

***'Oncommon'*** said Mr Peggotty.

*'And little Em'ly, and Mrs Gummidge?'*

***'On--common'***, said Mr Peggotty.

And following a further exchange Peggotty continues:

*…I was to come over and inquire for Mas'r Davy and give her dooty, humbly wishing him well and reporting of the fam'ly as they was **oncommon** toe-be-sure. Little Em'ly, you see, she'll write to my sister when I go back, as I see you and as you was similarly **oncommon**, and so we make it quite a merry-go-rounder.*

Clearly ***oncommon*** means something like "in the best of health" but not only is it not quoted in the OED - even as an historic archaism - but as one who grew up close to the Norfolk dialect, which Peggotty speaks, it is unfamiliar to me too.

Comment: My only idea (I don't buy into the 'uncommon' suggestion) is that it is a version of 'on-comen', meaning 'coming on' or 'coming along' nicely - 'comen' being a Middle English version of 'come'. That would certainly fit with the sense of the passage, and with  Peggotty's way of speaking. I haven't yet found anything else to support this though!

Answer (score 2):

Dickens frequently wrote his characters' dialog in [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), and his characters also frequently speak with non-standard grammar, often with characteristic quirks or catchphrases.

So I'd interpret *oncommon* as an eye-dialect representation of *uncommon*, being used as a shorthand for "uncommonly good" or "uncommonly well", and being repeated often by the same character as a quirk of her speech.

Comment: Norfolk dialect does tend to turn "un" into "on" - *onfortunately*. Indeed various English working-class accents have this feature. It was I sense an attempt by Dickens faithfully to reproduce the Norfolk accent.

Comment: In an article *Dickens as sociolinguist* Patricia Poussa draws attention to his undoubted grasp of the Norfolk accent which "he utilised in the speech of the Yarmouth fishermen, Ham and Daniel Peggoty" . She makes connections between Scandinavian languages and the particular variant of Norfolk dialect spoken in the Flegg area around Great Yarmouth, a place of known Viking settlement. Ref  *Writing in Non-Standard English, eds. Irma Taavitsainen, Gunnel Melchers and Paivi Pahta (Philadelphia 1999)*